# Bill pay sent multiple unauthorized house payments and caused an account overdraw. What should we do?

Tags: bank-of-america, overdraft

We have bill pay with Bank of America. We set up house payment for 12/02/19 which they paid. They also paid it again on 12/03/19 causing insufficient funds and an overdraft fee to our account as we only had approximately $175 in the bank.

My husband spent most of the day trying to sort this out. Our home loan bank stated that they would send us a check within 10 days. On 12/4/19 the amount for the 2nd house payment was returned and then bill pay immediately took it out and yet again sent payment to our home mortgage holder, causing yet another negative balance in our account and another overdraft fee.

My husband has spent two days going up to Bank of America, calling them and our mortgage company and trying to work this out online. We are both on disability and my husband has severe heart problems. All we want is for this insanity to stop, the overdraft fees to be returned along with our original $175.

How should we get this sorted out?

Comment: Is this the first time that this payment being made, or has the bill pay been in existence for awhile.

Comment: Make sure you talk to the manager. If you're on twitter (or maybe a relative or friend is), try tweeting your story (concisely!) at BofA. See if a local tv/newspaper has a consumer advocate.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot go to BoA and discuss it with them for you, obviously.
What you should verify is that in the bill payment section you didn't enter it as a *repeating payment*, and if you did, just cancel the repeats.

I have been using Bill Pay from BoA for the last 15 years, and never had any issue. It would be strange error if they make a payment repeating by themselves, so the assumption would be that you did it - maybe accidentially.

Comment: Every time I've had a problem with bill pay (not BoA) it's been due to PEBKAC.

Comment: This was not set up as repeating payment. The payments were taken out of our account and paid to mortgage company on 12/2, 12/3, 12/4.

Comment: @KarenShoults When you say "This was not set up as repeating payment", have you actually verified since the problem began that the payment is indeed not repeating? People make mistakes, and user interfaces can be poorly designed (sometimes intentionally so).

Comment: @KarenShoults As Tashus says, it sounds like it HAS been set up as a repeating payment... whether that was a mistake on your part of the bank's doesn't really matter at this stage, the first thing to do is to get the bank to DOUBLE-CHECK whether it HAS been set up as repeating, and to STOP the repeats if it has. Once that has been done, you can argue over who made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I bet BoA is going to sweet talk(AKA bullshit) it as "system error", while BoA likes many banks  [are known to conduct such "grey" practice as shown here](https://topclassactions.com/lawsuit-settlements/closed-settlements/836707-bank-america-overdraft-fees-class-action-settlement-2/) or [here](https://www.cnbc.com/2017/01/19/questionable-overdraft-fees-persist-lawsuit-alleges.html). 
In fact, computer systems will not do weird "glitches" unless somebody is tweaking the algorithm in the backroom. (Now you know the reason why they praise AI)

Ask the bank "politely" to rectify the "*mistake*". Don't forget to mention that you want to terminate those "**overdraft protection program**" according to [Consumer Financial Protection Bureau](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/) suggestion. Usually, those banks will "revert their mistake" to avoid dealing with the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau.

Nevertheless, if politeness doesn't work, you can always file a [complain to the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaint/).

(Update) 
As OP mentioned the bank staff blame it on floating checks. But according to the way [how check float works](https://www.thebalance.com/floating-checks-315303), this is not the case.

Comment: There was no sweet talking. In fact we have been accused of Floating Checks, it is our own fault and nothing they can do. There would be no benefit to sending our house payment 3 times in 3 days. We are at a loss in finding some resolution to this. Not only is our $175 gone but also another $75 in insufficient funds. Our checks come at the end of the month. Not only can we not pay our auto insurance we cannot even buy groceries so this is a very urgent matter to us. $175 is not a lot of money but it is when that is all you have. We are in desperate need of help.

Comment: @KarenShoults file your complain to Consumer Financial Protection Bureau. There is no point in wasting your time when BoA staff are trained to BS in such a situation. Prepare to join another class-action lawsuit.